# Combining Chef And Docker

Tags: docker, chef-infra, iaas

I am having hard time figuring how I should combine Chef and Docker to get the best of them.

Right now I am using Chef to automatically pull a docker image and create a container.
But things get messy when I want to change the configuration inside the container.

I read about knife container but I didn't understand how one can bootstrap a container and a new vm (on Amazon for example) all together.

Comment: What does it mean to "change the configuration inside the container"? How?

Comment: Don't change the configuration within the container. Design the container to use environment variables, which you set from Chef.

Comment: If you want to use chef within the container checkout the docs: https://docs.chef.io/containers.html and https://docs.chef.io/plugin_knife_container.html

Comment: I want to provision a vm with a docker container that runs replicated mysql and set the master server using Chef. Replication is set using the my.cnf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that if all you want to do is manage Docker images/containers, that you don't really need Chef.

Docker provides tools like:

1. Fig (http://www.fig.sh/), which brings up multiple containers as one logical unit.
2. Swarm (https://github.com/docker/swarm/), which allows you to abstract away the machines you have for deployments. For example, "My app needs 2GB of RAM, 1 CPU, 10GB of HD, which machine has available resources?"
3. Machine (https://github.com/docker/machine), which allows you to create VMs in the cloud in pretty much any provider.
4. A REST API (https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api/), which allows you to remotely start/stop containers etc.

In my opinion those suite of tools replace the need for Chef *if* all you're going to do is manage Docker images and containers.

As someone already noted, don't change configs after a container has started. Better to make a new image or restart the container. You could also mount the configs external to the container and modify them there, then restart the container.

Comment: Fig has been replaced by Docker Compose, and is now deprecated.